# Global member creation

Tags: visual-c++

How the global members can be created in vc++ 6.0 mfc project.

If I select globals option in WizardBar(WizardBar C++ class)
then (WizardBar C++ members),it display (No members - Create New Class...).

How to create the members for this globals class?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "global member". A member is, by definition, part of a class, and therefore /not/ global. Do you mean a global function or variable?

Comment: i know what is global function , but i am not getting in vc++ mfc classes how it can be created

Answer (score 0):

If you have any global functions in your project , that will displayed in the combo box.
To see just declare some c style function like this

int sum(int a ,int b) { return a+b;}

Now the combo box will display sum function.

"*No members - Create New Class...*" displayed in the combo box ,when no global function found in your project.

here "*Create New class ...*" conveys user that they can do right click to add new class to the project.